# AWS Backup - How to get notification from failed backups

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using AWS Backup to backup my resources. I would like to get notifications from failed backups, but the only way to check the status of backups is from the AWS Backup service page - there is nothing AWS Backup related on Cloudwatch metrics, I was thinking of creating SNS-topic from Cloudwatch metric but that doesn't seem to be possible now?

Another question - would there be any way to get weekly report from AWS Backup, like "There are 25 resources currently being backed up, and from the last 7 days there is 175 restore points available"?

Comment: Related: [Using Amazon SNS to Track AWS Backup Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/sns-notifications.html)

Comment: If I understood correctly, the events that could be listed that way are only manual ones. So there would be no notification from the automatic backup, that happens according to the backup plan?

Of course I found the answer to my second question from that link, thanks for that!

Comment: This shows how to get notifications of failed backups only: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aws-backup-failed-job-notification/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create an SNS topic, add AWS Backup as a trusted entity in the resource-based policy of the SNS topic:

```
{
"Sid": "__console_pub_0",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"Service": "backup.amazonaws.com"
},
"Action": "SNS:Publish",
"Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:{accountId}:test"
}
```

then turns on notifications for that topic and add BACKUP_JOB_COMPLETED event by the following AWS documentation: 
[Using Amazon SNS to Track AWS Backup Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/sns-notifications.html).

Each time when AWS Backup job is completed or failed you will be informed to subscribed email address in SNS topic.
However, I can't find a way to [customize notification](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=307367).